# toggle visibilty after fadeout with jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, toggle, visibility, fadeout

I have an alert div I show for some time then fadeout. I want it to be visible again so that if it is needed again it will show. However I found that if I try to do this after the fadeout the visibility remains hidden with this code:

```
if (alert_div.is(":visible")) {
   alert_div.not('.alert-important').delay(2000).fadeOut(350).promise().done(function () {
     alert_div.empty().toggle();
 });
```

So I made this that is working but do I really need to do like this?
Why doesn't the first one work?

```
if (alert_div.is(":visible")) {
     alert_div.not('.alert-important').delay(2000).fadeOut(350).promise().done(function () {
         alert_div.empty();
     });
}else{
      alert_div.toggle();
      alert_div.not('.alert-important').delay(2000).fadeOut(350).promise().done(function () {
         alert_div.empty();
     });
}
```

Comment: There's no point in using `toggle()` if you already know whether the DIV is visible or not. Use `hide()` or `show()` explicitly, to make it clear what you're doing.

Comment: I can't see why the original code doesn't work. Can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar ... I tried with show() and it's working. I don't know why it doesn't with toggle().

Comment: Maybe because it runs during animation it still thinks the DIV is visible, so it hides it. But I'd assume that the `.done()` function wouldn't run until it has completely faded.

Comment: Never used it with `.promise().done()` - try with the done callback `.fadeOut(350, function() { `

Comment: Could also check `if (alert_div.is(":animated"))`  https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand what you are suggesting.